# Inconsistency in App Engine datastore vs what I know it should be from parsing the same data source locally

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

This may be a trivial question, but I was just hoping to get some practical experience from people who may know more about this than I do.

I wanted to generate a database in GAE from a very large series of XML files -- as a form of validation, I am calculating statistics on the GAE datastore, and I know there should be ~16,000 entities, but when I perform a count, I'm getting more on the order of 12,000.

The way I'm doing counting is basically I perform a filter, fetch a page of 1000 entities, and then spin up task queues for each entity (using its key). Each task queue then adds "1" to a counter that I'm storing.

I think I may have juiced the datastore writes too much; I set the rate of my task queues to 50/s.. I did get some writing errors, but not nearly enough to justify the 4,000 difference. Could it be possible that I was rushing the counting calls too much that it lead to inconsistency? Would slowing the rate that I process task queues to something like 5/s solve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need a task for each entity just to count it???

Comment: I need to pull other data from each entity to calculate other statistics that can be quite large

Comment: Then use the code I suggested, just remove "setKeysOnly()" if you need to actually extract your entities. I also updated my answer.

Comment: You haven't said how you are accumulating your statistics, if you are using parallel tasks are you sure you are updating your counter(s) consistently (ie out of order writes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can count your entities very easily (no tasks and almost for free):

```
int total = 0;
Query q = new Query("entity_kind").setKeysOnly();
// set your filter on this query

QueryResultList<Entity> results;
Cursor cursor = null;
FetchOptions queryOptions = FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(1000).chunkSize(1000);

do {
    if (cursor != null) {
        queryOptions.startCursor(cursor);
    }
    results = datastore.prepare(q).asQueryResultList(queryOptions);
    total += results.size();
    cursor = results.getCursor();
} while (results.size() == 1000);

System.out.println("Total entities: " + total);
```

UPDATE:

If looping like I suggested takes too long, you can spin a task for every 100/500/1000 entities - it's definitely more efficient than creating a task for each entity. Even very complex calculations should take milliseconds in Java if done right.

For example, each task can retrieve a batch of entities, spin a new task (and pass a query cursor to this new task), and then proceed with your calculations.

Comment: Is there really such a performance penalty for spinning up task queues? I agree it isn't necessary, but I have such bad luck with GAE shutting down tasks that I'm trying to split them out as much as possible. This is the only way I can think of how to engineer around GAE.

Comment: Yes, spinning 100-1000 times more tasks than necessary is a major performance penalty. If you have 16 (or even 32) tasks instead of 16,000, you won't need to worry about the processing rate. I never had problems with tasks, by the way. They worked as expected for me.